# How to get the minimum position size or quantity for a market?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm looking for an equivalent of the `syminfo.mintick` for the minimum order/position size. I'd like to round an order size calculation to that precision, e.g. `0.000001` for `BINANCE:BTCBUSDPERP` or `0.001` for `BINANCE:SOLBUSD`

Is there such a built-in in v5 or how can it be calculated?

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with the following calculated precision for the position quantity. It's not perfect, as depends on at least one trade being opened by the strategy tester. Also, due to strategy tester unfixed rounding (i.e. the position size may round to a lower number of decimals, e.g. `1.420` → `1.42`), the precision may be off initially.

```
// The calculated number of digits to round position quantity to
var int posQtyPrec  = na
float   posSize     = position_size

// Calculate the rounding precision for position size
posQtyPrec := math.max(str.length(str.tostring(math.abs(posSize)))
 - str.pos(str.tostring(math.abs(posSize)), '.') - 1, nz(posQtyPrec))
```

One may add the required minimum precision to `nz()` to have a reasonable starting point.

Maybe someone finds it useful.